# android rotate animation reduce calculations and make animation smooth

Tags: java, android, animation, custom-painting

I'm trying to draw a custom rotating animation. This is the output of my code.

[image]

Basically every circle has small sub circles. Only issue is, sometimes animation skip some frames and animation looks broken. My guess is since this calculation is time consuming some frames are missing.

My question is what is the best way to improve this and keep animation smooth.
Is it possible to just calculate for first frame and rotate the canvas so we can reduce the calculations?

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);    
    int startRadius = 20;
    int endRadius = 400;
    int circleCount = 20;
    int circleDistance = (int) (((endRadius - startRadius) / (float) circleCount));

    for (int i = 0; i < circleCount; i++) {
        int radius = startRadius + i * circleDistance;
        canvas.drawCircle(center.x, center.y, radius, mPaint);

        int subCircles=i+1;
        double angleSegment = Math.PI * 2 / subCircles;
        for (int segment = 0; segment < subCircles; segment++) {
            double angle = angleSegment * segment + shiftAngle;
            double x = Math.cos(angle) * radius;
            double y = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
            canvas.drawCircle((float) (x + center.x), (float) (y + center.y), 6, pointPaint);
        }

    }
}
```

Animator

```
public void startAnim() {
    rotateAnim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 100);
    rotateAnim.setDuration(1000);
    rotateAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotateAnim.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
        shiftAngle += Math.PI / 180;
        View.this.invalidate();
    });
    rotateAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    rotateAnim.start();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can precalculate the center coordinates of the small circles at `shiftAngle = 0` and store them in arrays. You can draw them first and then rotate them `Math.PI / 180` with the following formula.

```
 newX = Math.cos(Math.PI / 180) * x - Math.sin(Math.PI / 180) * y;
 newY = Math.sin(Math.PI / 180) * x + Math.cos(Math.PI / 180) * y;
```

Since `Math.sin(Math.PI / 180)` and `Math.cos(Math.PI / 180)` are constants. They can be calculated outside the loop in advance.

You can push sin and cos calculations out of the loop by doing this.

Comment: thanks.i see with this i could save some computational time.but i still wonder is it possible to draw and just rotate the drawn canvas without calculating for another frame